# Enviar datos de un Activity a otro en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un layout que contiene un `gridview` y otro en el cual contiene un `textview` y un `imageview`, en uno captura imágenes y otro texto, al darle click a la imagen lo que quiero que el texto viaje a otro layout.

Este es mi Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String[] web = {"Android", "Historia",
                "Matematica"};

        int[] imageId = {R.drawable.blue,
                R.drawable.green, R.drawable.red,};

        final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.grid_text);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);

                intent.putExtra("curso", adapter.getItem(position).toString());

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Al parecer en el `putExtra` está el problema.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar un valor a otra Activity usa Extras en el Intent:

```
String valor = "hola mundo"

Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("valor", valor);
startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el valor en la otra Activity es:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();

String miValor = extra.getString("valor");
```

Para recibir el valor asegúrate que:

- El nombre del valor recibido sea el mismo que el enviado.
- El tipo del
  dato recibido sea el mismo que enviamos. (por ejemplo: Si envías un
  String utiliza .getString() para recibirlo, si es int utiliza
  getInt(), etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres enviar la `posicion` de un elemento del `GridView` a otra `activity`, una forma es
precisamente con `Intent` `putExtra`, de esta forma:

```
   // de esta forma lo envías como String
intent.putExtra("curso", Integer.toString(position));

   // de esta otra, lo envías como int
intent.putExtra("curso2", position);
```

En la `Activity` receptora lo recibes con `Bundle`, dentro de `onCreate`:

```
      // inicializas el String y el int de esta forma:
    String value1 = "";
    int value2 = 0;

      // luego obtienes los valores que le envió la otra activity
      // para String declaras default "", y para int un 0
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras !=null){
        value1 = extras.getString("curso", "");
        value2 = extras.getInt("curso2",0);
    }
      // configuras los valores
    textView.setText(value1);
    textView2.setText(Integer.toString(value2));
```