# Envio de datos String entre Activities , usarlos en onClick()

Tags: android, string, date, activity, android-intent

he estado realizando el envio de un dato string a otra activity se llama una caculate y desde esa a historial pero no me ha funcionado alguien me puede decir cual sera el inconveniente.
Gracias!

se declaran las variables 
String d;
String valor,x;
dentro de una funcion llamada calcular estoy realizando esta operacion.
x=valor;[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    Intent miinten = new Intent(Calculate.this, Hitorial.class);
    miinten.putExtra("x",x);
```

en la otra clase historial estoy recibiendo los datos dentro de un boton para ver historial asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al realizar la ejecucion me aparecen lo siguiente en debug cuando realizo la accion de ver historial y presionar el boton.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede decir que es no recibe el parametro porque ? y como lo puedo solucionar. 
Gracias

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Bienvenido @Julian es importante realices tus preguntas agregando el código como texto, en este caso revisa también los enlaces que comenta Kacospro, es importante. Con respecto a tu caso, el valor que obtienes lo debes evaluar dentro de onCreate() y posteriormente al dar click en la vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí existe un detalle importante a comentar: **los valores del `Bundle` se reciben en `onCreate()`, debes obtener aquí los valores del `Bundle`, guardarlos en variables y posteriormente podrás utilizarlos, en este caso dentro de la acción clic del botón.**

Si lo tratas de evaluar de esta forma, en realidad no estas recibiendo un `Bundle` con datos, por lo tanto no obtendrás el valor.

```
 @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(bundle != null){       
            vista.setText("x"+ bundle.getString("x"));
         }    
        }
    });
```

Esta sería la forma correcta, Obtén el valor y almacenalo para despues usarlo al dar clic en la vista:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   //*Obten el bundle y obtén el valor de "x".
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(bundle != null){
       valorX = bundle.getString("x");
   }

  ...
  ...

   //*Ahora aquí puedes usar el valor de "x":

   ver2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            vista.setText("x"+ valorX);
      }
    });


}
```

Revisa:

[Enviar datos entre activities](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36902/enviar-datos-entre-activities)

Comment: Hola Jorge, muchas gracias por tu aporte pero sigue igual no me funciona, me aparece null en pantalla donde deberia salir el dato :(

Comment: tienes otro detalle, después de estas lineas:   Intent miinten = new Intent(Calculate.this, Hitorial.class);
    miinten.putExtra("x",x);  debes realizar startActivity(miinten); no lo estas realizando  me parece que estas realizando otro intent, agrega tu clase como texto para comentarte donde esta ahora este problema

Comment: Jorge mira aqui estan las nuevas imagenes probando la opcion que me dijieste, pero me sigue saliendo null al dato que recibe y no veo que sera gracias

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/199016/envio-de-datos-de-un-activity-a-otro-android

Comment: De acuerdo a lo mencionado antes  startActivity(miinten) no lo agrege por que no quiero que se inicie automaticamente esa activity donde envio el dato, nose si ese sea el inconveniente

Comment: Jorge agrege el  startActivity(miinten) y funciona amigo graciasss

Comment: pero se me incia automaticamente la otra activity ... mmmm

Comment: hehehe, lo que sucede es que estas realizando otro intent en el cual no se agrega el valor a enviar, busca ese otro startActivity() y eliminalo ya que probablemente no lo necesitas. @julian

Comment: Gracias, tienes idea de alguno ? que me pueda servir

Answer (score -2):

Es probable que el valor no se recibió correctamente en la activity **Historial.class**

Te recomiendo que realices lo siguiente.

Declarar una variable a nivel de clase por ejemplo.

```
private String Micalculo;
```

Luego asigna el valor a la variable `Micalculo` pero en el `Oncreate`().

```
public void Oncreate(bundle SavedInstanceState){
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(bundle !=null){
    Micalculo = bundle.getString("x");  
  }
}
```

Y luego utiliza la variable `Micalculo` en tu método `Onclick`.

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero realice los pasos que mencionaste y me sigue mostrando lo mismo en el debug

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                vista.setText(Micalculo);} asi llame la variable desde el boton

Comment: Podrias detallar mas el error ya que la imagen no se llega a ver casi nada

Comment: Claro cuando presiono el boton de ver me sale esto en el debug, cada vez que presiono aparece una linea

Comment: D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Comment: Esto significa que el botón no realizó ninguna acción,puedes primero imprimir en log la variable Micalculo,asi System.out.println(Micalculo); en el Oncreate para saber si en realidad se recibió alguna dato? o utilizar el Toast

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198457/enviar-datos-de-un-activity-a-otro-en-android-studio

Comment: Gracias Emilio, revisare como tu me dices y te cuento

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con esto por favor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209025/android-studio-bar-chart-graficar