# EditText.getText() no funciona

Tags: android, android-fragment

intento hacer un CRUD en Android(java), el proyecto esta basado en un navigation drawer como menu y una Activity que funciona como contenedor de los fragmentos que uso en el proyecto para dicho crud.
Tengo un solo fragment en el que quiero implementar las funcionalidades de registro y modificacion de datos.
A continuacion la actividad principal donde se da la navegabilidad del menu principal como del menu del toolbar (boton superior derecho)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public int origen;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);
        //OMITO TODO EL CODIGO AUTOGENERADO PARA CONTROLES TOOLBAR Y NAVIGACION
        //incio fragment ptincipal
        Fragment fgmCatalogo = new CatalogoFragment();
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fgmCatalogo).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //Dado que el programa tiene muchos CRUD y todos tiene la misma estructura llamo al fragment detalle desde un mismo boton en ese menu     
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            switch (origen)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Aqui abro el fragmento de detalle para crear un nuevo cliente
                    fragment = new ClienteDetalleFragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            Bundle arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putInt("accion",0);
            fragment.setArguments(arg);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_close)
       {
           new LoginResponse().borrarDatos();
           Intent actHome = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
           startActivity(actHome);
       }
       else
       {
           Fragment fragment = null;
           switch(item.getItemId()){
               case R.id.nav_vender:
                   origen = 1;
                   fragment = new CatalogoFragment();
                   break;
               case R.id.nav_inventario:
                   origen = 2;
                   fragment = new menuInventario();
                   break;
               case R.id.nav_clientes:
                   origen = 3;
                   fragment = new ClienteFragment();
                   break;
               case R.id.nav_ventas:
                   origen = 4;
                   fragment = new Venta();
                   break;
               case R.id.nav_reportes:
                   origen = 5;
                   break;
               default://empresa
                   origen = 6;
                   break;
           }
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
           DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

Ahora tengo dos fragments **ClienteFragment** donde se carga la lista de registros

```
public class ClienteFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recicler;
    Cliente[] clientes;
    Cliente clienteSel;

    private menuInventario.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public ClienteFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente, container, false);
        confView(fragment);
        return  fragment;
    }

    public void confView(View view){
        recicler = view.findViewById(R.id.lstvClientes);
        recicler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(App.getAppContext()));//,LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false));
        //recicler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(App.getAppContext(),2));
        mostrarDatos();
    }

    public void  mostrarDatos(){
        new Api().solicitud(Api.getService().getClientes(new LoginResponse().leerDatos().getIdNegocio()), new RespuestaListener() {
            @Override
            public void onData(JsonElement data) {
                clientes = new Gson().fromJson(data, Cliente[].class);
                SubtitleAdapter adapter = new SubtitleAdapter(clientes);
                adapter.setOnClickListener(new ItemSelected());
                recicler.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }

    class ItemSelected implements View.OnClickListener{

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//Abro fragment de detalles para modificar datos
            clienteSel = clientes[recicler.getChildAdapterPosition(v)];
            Bundle arg = new Bundle();
            arg.putSerializable("clienteSel",clienteSel);
            arg.putInt("accion",1); //1 es indicador de modificacion
            Fragment detalles = new ClienteDetalleFragment();
            detalles.setArguments(arg);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,detalles).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

y **ClienteDetalleFragment** donde se generan las acciones update y create

```
public class ClienteDetalleFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private int accion;

    EditText txtNombres, txtCedula, txtCelular, txtDireccion;
    Button btnRegistar;

    public ClienteDetalleFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente_detalle, container, false);
        confView(view);
        return view;
    }
    private void confView(View v) {
        txtNombres = v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreCliente);
        txtCedula = v.findViewById(R.id.txtIdentificacionCliente);
        txtCelular = v.findViewById(R.id.txtCelularCliente);
        txtDireccion = v.findViewById(R.id.txtDireccionSolo);
        btnRegistar = v.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarCliente);
        btnRegistar.setOnClickListener(this);
        Bundle arg = getArguments();
        accion = arg.getInt("accion");
        if (accion == 1) {
            cliente = (Cliente) arg.getSerializable("clienteSel");
            mostrarDatos();
        }
    }

    private void mostrarDatos() {
        txtNombres.setText(cliente.getNombres());
        txtCedula.setText(cliente.getIdentificacion());
        txtCelular.setText(cliente.getCelular());
        txtDireccion.setText(cliente.getDireccion());
    }

    private  boolean validarCampos(){
        boolean resp = false;
        if (txtNombres.getText().length() == 0){
            Mensaje.simple("Nombre es requerido", 0);
        }
        else if (txtCedula.getText().length() == 0){
            Mensaje.simple("Cedula/Pasaporte es requerido", 0);
        }
        else if (txtCelular.getText().length() == 0){
            Mensaje.simple("Celular es requerido", 0);
        }
        else if (txtDireccion.getText().length() == 0){
            Mensaje.simple("Correo es requerido", 0);
        }
        else {
            cliente.setIdentificacion(txtCedula.getText().toString());
            cliente.setCelular(txtCelular.getText().toString());
            cliente.setDireccion(txtDireccion.getText().toString());
            cliente.setNombres(txtNombres.getText().toString());
            cliente.setIdNegocio(new LoginResponse().leerDatos().getIdNegocio());
            resp = true;
        }
        return resp;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (validarCampos()) {
               if (accion == 0) {
                new Api().solicitud(Api.getService().postCliente(cliente), new RespuestaListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onData(JsonElement data) {
                        getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                new Api().solicitud(Api.getService().putCliente(cliente.getId(), cliente), new RespuestaListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onData(JsonElement data) {
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();// getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Ahora, cuando quiero modificar datos, llamando el fragment de detalle desde el fragment cliente, la lectura de datos de la pantalla es exitosa y la modificacion no genera errores, pero cuando llamo al mismo fragment de detalles desde el main activity para crear un registro de cliente, la lectura de datos falla y me genera un error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.kevtho.crud.Model.Cliente.setIdentificacion(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at com.kevtho.crud.Controller.Cliente.ClienteDetalleFragment.onClick(ClienteDetalleFragment.java:87)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
```

Linea 87: cliente.setIdentificacion(txtCedula.getText().toString());

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el error te lo da porque la variable *cliente* no está inicializada. En el código solo la inicializas cuando el valor del parámetro *accion* es 1 pero, de los dos sitios donde abres el fragmento de clientes, solo en uno informas ese parámetro y, además, con un valor de 0

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo habia notado la falta del inicializador de la clase

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo indica el error mostrado en el LogCat:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.kevtho.crud.Model.Cliente.setIdentificacion(java.lang.String)' on
>   a null object reference

el método setIdentificacion() no puede ser llamado porque la instancía de Cliente no se ha inicializado. Estas definiendo una variable para esto:

```
private Cliente cliente;
```

pero no esta siendo inicializada.

Te sugiero obtengas los datos del `bundle` en el método `onCreateView()` ya que podría estar sucediendo algo similar a lo descrito en esta pregunta:

[Envio de datos String entre Activities , usarlos en onClick()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198460/envio-de-datos-string-entre-activities-usarlos-en-onclick/198575?noredirect=1)

realiza este cambio:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente_detalle, container, false);

        Bundle arg = getArguments();
        accion = arg.getInt("accion");
        if (accion == 1) {
            cliente = (Cliente) arg.getSerializable("clienteSel");
            mostrarDatos();
        }

        confView(view);
        return view;
    }
    private void confView(View v) {
        txtNombres = v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreCliente);
        txtCedula = v.findViewById(R.id.txtIdentificacionCliente);
        txtCelular = v.findViewById(R.id.txtCelularCliente);
        txtDireccion = v.findViewById(R.id.txtDireccionSolo);
        btnRegistar = v.findViewById(R.id.btnRegistrarCliente);
        btnRegistar.setOnClickListener(this);
      /*  Bundle arg = getArguments();
        accion = arg.getInt("accion");
        if (accion == 1) {
            cliente = (Cliente) arg.getSerializable("clienteSel");
            mostrarDatos();
        }*/
    }
```